# Can't view JSP page

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat

On my apache tomcat server, I've had a page, index.jsp, running for several weeks. Today however, when I refreshed the page nothing appears, the only error says that there is no resource and the page source is completely empty. I use the URL:
http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp
I ensured that the directory is correct and the port is also correct. I placed some test HTML files under that directory as well but none of them can be viewed either. The server also started without any errors.

Comment: Well, index.jsp is just a test file:

         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <body>

       <h1>Test</h1>


        </body>
      </html>

Comment: check your capitalization of test...maybe its supposed to be Test or something like that

Comment: Its lowercase, it shouldn't matter in my opinion, its the same URL I've been using for a while and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Tomcat temp/, conf/Catalina and work/ folders. Removes the webapps/ your application war or file folder. And then restarts the Tomcat and let us know how is going?